# configure pipelines and deploy react app on azure devops and azure app services

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

my package.json has the following in scripts section

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
"lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
"lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
"build-package-css": "cp src/assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css dist/material-dashboard-react.css",
"build-package": "npm run build-package-css && babel src --out-dir dist"
```

}

so do I have to write steps to build pipeline to do all these?

Comment: hi.  i yet to to implement this solution yet. i will update thanks

Comment: If there are any updates. please feel free to let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `npm` task and configure the Command `install` to install npm packages
2. Add task npm, select the command field, choose from the dropdown “custom” and for the `command and argument` enter `run build`, we can configure the package.json file in the field `Working folder that contains package.json`
3. Add task `CopyFiles`, `ArchiveFiles` and `PublishBuildArtifacts` to publish artifact.
4. Create release pipeline->select the artifact as resource->add task `Deploy Azure App Service` to deploy your react app to azure app service.

Note: We need create app service in the Azure Portal and configure service connect in the project settings.

You can refer to this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/deploying-react-apps-to-azure-with-azure-devops/) and [doc](https://www.kieferconsulting.com/2020/06/25/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-azure-using-devops-pipeline/) for more details.